# Angular 9 - Cannot change body background with css variable

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using custom color variables in order to change button colors and it is working fine. I am using elementRef.

Problem is when I try to change body background color, even when I point to the variable, body is still taking default color.

```
   :root{
 --body-background-color: #f7b219;
}

body,

html{
  background-color: var(--body-background-color) !important;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```css
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #f7b219;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Comment: More relevant on using CSS variables here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var

Comment: Yes, I have just like that in my code but it is still using default value.

Comment: OK. Can I see more of your code? Is the webpage live on internet that I could check it? Or also, apart from Angular are you using other libraries/frameworks that could be overriding this custom CSS? Because that code is 100% valid, that I am sure.

Comment: Yes, you were right!! I had a syntax problem in my code... Thanx!

Comment: Glad I could help!